# How can I remove the screen lock during phone calls on Android 4.4.4?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, calls

How can I remove the screen lock during phone calls on Android 4.4.4? I have a Samsung Galaxy Core 2, and whenever I'm on a call I have to tap the screen two times to unlock it. Is it possible to remove it?